# Perl - Removing unwanted elements from an arrayref

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm writing a script that parses the "pure-ftpwho -s" command to get a list of the current transfers. But when a user disconnects from the FTP and reconnects back and resumes a transfer, the file shows up twice. I want to remove the ghosted one with Perl. After parsing, here is what the arrayref looks like (dumped with Data::Dumper)

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'status' => 'DL',
        'percent' => '20',
        'speed' => '10',
        'file' => 'somefile.txt',
        'user' => 'user1',
        'size' => '14648'
      },
      {
        'status' => 'DL',
        'percent' => '63',
        'speed' => '11',
        'file' => 'somefile.txt',
        'user' => 'user1',
        'size' => '14648'
      },
      {
        'status' => 'DL',
        'percent' => '16',
        'speed' => '60',
        'file' => 'somefile.txt',
        'user' => 'user2',
        'size' => '14648'
      }
    ];
```

Here user1 and user2 are downloading the same file, but user1 appears twice because the first one is a "ghost". What's the best way to check and remove elements that I don't need (in this case the first element of the arrayref). The condition to check is that - If the "file" key and "user" key is the same, then delete the hashref that contains the smaller value of "percent" key (if they're the same then delete all except one).

Comment: Please read `perldoc perldsc` (also available online at http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order in the original arrayref doesn't matter, this should work:

```
my %users;
my @result;

for my $data (@$arrayref) {
    push @{ $users{$data->{user}.$data->{file}} }, $data;
}

for my $value (values %users) {
    my @data = sort { $a->{percent} <=> $b->{percent} } @$value;
    push @result, $data[-1];
}
```

This can definitely be improved for efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution in this case would have been to use a hash when parsing the log file. Put all information into a hash, say `%log`, keyed by `user` and `file`:

```
$log{$user}->{$file} = {
    'status' => 'DL',
    'percent' => '20',
    'speed' => '10',
    'size' => '14648'
};
```

etc. Latter entries in the log file would overwrite earlier ones. Alternatively, you can choose to overwrite entries with lower percent completed with ones that have higher completion rates.

Using a hash would get rid of a lot of completely superfluous code working around the choice of the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, here's my (slightly) alternative approach. Again, it doesn't preserve the original order:

```
my %most_progress;

for my $data ( sort { $b->{percent} <=> $a->{percent} } @$data ) {
    next if exists $most_progress{$data->{user}.$data->{file}};
    $most_progress{$data->{user}.$data->{file}} = $data;
}

my @clean_data = values %most_progress;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will preserve order:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = [ ... ]; # As posted.

my %pct;
for my $i ( 0 .. $#{$data} ){
    my $r = $data->[$i];
    my $k = join '|', $r->{file}, $r->{user};
    next if exists $pct{$k} and $pct{$k}[1] >= $r->{percent};
    $pct{$k} = [$i, $r->{percent}];
}

@$data = @$data[sort map $_->[0], values %pct];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my %check; 

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#{$arrayref}; $i++) { 
  my $transfer = $arrayref->[$i]; 

  # check the transfer for user and file 
  my $key = $transfer->{user} . $transfer->{file};  
  $check{$key} = { } if ( !exists $check{$key} ); 

  if ( $transfer->{percent} <= $check{$key}->{percent} ) { 
    # undefine this less advanced transfer 
    $arrayref->[$i] = undef; 

  } else { 
    # remove the other transfer 
    $arrayref->[$check{$key}->{index}] = undef if exists $check{$key}->{index}; 

    # set the new standard 
    $check{$key} = { index => $i, percent => $transfer->{percent} } 
  } 
}  

# remove all undefined transfers     
$arrayref = [ grep { defined $_ } @$arrayref ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on the theme with [`Perl6::Gather`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl6-Gather/)

```
use Perl6::Gather;

my @cleaned = gather {
    my %seen;
    for (sort { $b->{percent} <=> $a->{percent} } @$data) {
        take unless $seen{ $_->{user} . $_->{file} }++;
    }
};
```